# kernel module problem

Tags: kernel, iptables, firewall

i have problem with iptable when i trying to run this command iptable -L the output is `

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-186-generic
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

i tried to run this command

```
sudo apt-get install –reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

` but it's not solving the problem so
how i install missing module ?

Comment: Is this a physical computer or a hosted account? iptables is sometimes missing from hosted stuff.

Comment: You are using typographic dash ("`–`") in the command. Try to use correct command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)` and then report back.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a very old DigitalOcean droplet that I had upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 18.04 over the years.

The answer, I believe, is to upgrade the kernel via the DigitalOcean dashboard, but for some reason that option was disabled for my server. I think it is just too old now and I will need to migrate to a new droplet.

I suspect if the command to install the image didn't work for you, you may be in a similar situation.

https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/kernel/